# Why do I get "Global symbol '$href_array' requires specific package name" in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I can't seem to get these arrays to work. I'm getting errors along the following lines:

```
Global symbol '$href_array' requires specific package name
```

What does this mean? Here's part of my code:

```
sub scrape {
my ( $self, $DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname ) = @_;
my ($dbh, $query, $result, $array);
my $DNS = "dbi:mysql:$DBname:$DBhost:3306";
$dbh = DBI->connect($DNS, $DBuser, $DBpass ) or die $DBI::errstr;
if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) && ( -e 'href_w_' . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt" ) ) {
    open  ERROR_W, "error_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
    open  M_HREF_W, "m_href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
    open  HREF_W, "href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
    my @m_error_array = ( split( '|||', <ERROR_W> ) );
    my @m_href_array = ( split( '|||', <M_HREF_W> ) );
    my @href_array = ( split( '|||', <HREF_W> ) );
    close ( ERROR_W );
    close ( M_HREF_W );
    close ( HREF_W );
}else{
    my @m_error_array;
    my @m_href_array;
    my @href_array = ( $self->{_url} );
}
my $z = 0;
while( $href_array ){
    if( defined( $self->{_x_more} ) && $z == $self->{_x_more} ) {
        break;
    }
    if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) ) {
        $self->write( 'm_href_w', @m_href_array );
        $self->write( 'href_w', @href_array );
        $self->write( 'error_w', @m_error_array );
    }
    $self->{_link_count} = scalar @m_href_array;
}
```

}

FIXED:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use URI;
use File::Basename;
use DBI;

package Crawler;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _url => shift,
        _max_link => 0,
        _local => 1
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;

}
sub process_image {
    my ($self, $process_image) = @_;
    $self->{_process_image} = $process_image;
}
sub local {
    my ($self, $local) = @_;
    $self->{_local} = $local;
}
sub max_link {
    my ($self, $max_link) = @_;
    $self->{_max_link} = $max_link;
}
sub x_more {
    my ($self, $x_more) = @_;
    $self->{_x_more} = $x_more;
}
sub resolve_href {
    my ($base, $href) = @_;
    my $uri = URI->new($href);
    return $uri->rel($base);    
}
sub write {
    my ( $self, $ref, $data ) = @_;
    open FILE, '>>' . $ref . '_' . $self->{_process_image} . '.txt';
    print FILE join( '|||', $data );
    close( FILE );
}
sub scrape {
    my @m_error_array;
    my @m_href_array;
    my @href_array;
    my ( $self, $DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname ) = @_;
    my ($dbh, $query, $result, $array);
    my $DNS = "dbi:mysql:$DBname:$DBhost:3306";
    $dbh = DBI->connect($DNS, $DBuser, $DBpass ) or die $DBI::errstr;
    if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) && ( -e 'href_w_' . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt" ) ) {
        open  ERROR_W, "error_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        open  M_HREF_W, "m_href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        open  HREF_W, "href_w_" . $self->{_process_image} . ".txt";
        my @m_error_array = ( split( '|||', <ERROR_W> ) );
        my @m_href_array = ( split( '|||', <M_HREF_W> ) );
        my @href_array = ( split( '|||', <HREF_W> ) );
        close ( ERROR_W );
        close ( M_HREF_W );
        close ( HREF_W );
    }else{
        @href_array = ( $self->{_url} );
    }
    my $z = 0;
    while( @href_array ){
        if( defined( $self->{_x_more} ) && $z == $self->{_x_more} ) {
            break;
        }
        if( defined( $self->{_process_image} ) ) {
            $self->write( 'm_href_w', @m_href_array );
            $self->write( 'href_w', @href_array );
            $self->write( 'error_w', @m_error_array );
        }
        $self->{_link_count} = scalar @m_href_array;
    }
}
1;

#$query = "SELECT * FROM `actwebdesigns.co.uk` ORDER BY ID DESC";
#$result = $dbh->prepare($query);
#$result->execute();
#while( $array = $result->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
#    print $array->{'URL'} . "\n";
#}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code probably won't work the way you think it will. Take, for example, this block:

```
}else{
    my @m_error_array;
    my @m_href_array;
    my @href_array = ( $self->{_url} );
}
```

What this does is declare three arrays. That's all fine and good, but because you've used `my`, they "disappear" when they go out of scope at the end of the `else{}` block. You probably want to declare them up at the top, before your `if...else` block and remove the duplicated declarations from both blocks in the `if...else` section.

Then, you're probably trying to iterate over the `@href_array` list. You'll want to change your `while()` to something like:

```
foreach my $href_array ( @href_array ) {
    ...
}
```

All that said, kudos for putting `use strict` in your code (it must be there, or else you wouldn't have received the warning you did). That's an important thing that programmers new to Perl greatly benefit from, because it warns them about exactly this problem!

Comment: why am I not alowed to use break?

Comment: @Phil Jackson, in Perl, break is spelled `last`.  (Actually, Perl 5.10 & up do have a `break` keyword, but it's not equivalent to C`s `break`; it's used with the new [`given`/`when` construct](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements).)

Answer (score 2):

It means you are using an undeclared variable `$href_array`.  You need to rewrite this line:

```
while( $href_array ){
```

to something like:

```
foreach my $element (@href_array) {
```

...although a bit more context is needed in this code to be able to understand what it is doing -- for example, you open a database connection in the `scrape` method (`$dbh = ...`), but never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code includes `while($href_array)` but you don't declare a variable called `$href_array`.

You may have meant `@href_array` (these are not the same variable), although you don't seem to modify this array inside the loop.

Comment: i get the same with `while(@href_array)`

Answer (score 0):

In all these answers no one bothers to tell you that the [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) pragma enforces some more stringent coding practices in Perl. See its docs for the details. We explain it fully in *Learning Perl* too :)

When you get a warning you don't understand, you can get more information with the [diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html). Here's an example:

```
use strict;
use diagnostics;

while( $href ) { 1 };
```

Here's the extended error message:

```
Execution of /Users/brian/Desktop/t aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
    (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates 
    that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or "state"), 
    declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say 
    which package the global variable is in (using "::").
```

Comment: I actually did in my answer: "All that said, kudos for putting use strict in your code (it must be there, or else you wouldn't have received the warning you did). That's an important thing that programmers new to Perl greatly benefit from, because it warns them about exactly this problem!"

Comment: No, you just mentioned strict. You didn't explain what it was doing. You also buried it at the end because you got distracted by everything else going on. Always put the important stuff first.